# Require Web3 module inside nodejs webworkers

Tags: node.js, web3js

I'm facing an issue when I do require('web3') inside a worker.
I have a main thread which is creating 3 workers on every call.
Each worker is using require('web3'). Main thread is also using require('web3')

It works for the first call to the Program, but nodejs crashes on the second call to the program.
Strangely, this issue happens when I use require('web3') in the main thread. I cannot avoid this because I need web3 in the main thread as well.

Is there an issue with updation of require cache by any chance?

```
express = require('express');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Web3 = require('web3')
app = express();
path = require('path')


const {
  Worker, MessageChannel, MessagePort, isMainThread, parentPort
} = require('worker_threads');


const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port${port}`);
}); 

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    (async() => {
            await test();
        
    })();
});



async function test() {
    console.log("\n\n*** starting threads***\n\n");
    return new Promise((parentResolve, parentReject) => {   

        threadCount = 2;
        const promises = [];
        for (let idx = 0; idx < threadCount; idx += 1) {
                var testdata = {};
                testdata.id = idx+1;
                //testdata.web3 = web3;
                promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    var worker = null;
                    try {
                      worker = new Worker("./scripts/workers/testworker.js", {
                      workerData: testdata});

                    } catch(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                  worker.on("exit", () => {
                      console.log("Worker exiting");
                    resolve()
                  });
                  worker.on("message", (result) => {
                      console.log(result);

                  });
                  
                  worker.on("error", (result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    

                  });
                
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    parentReject(error);
                }));
              }
              
              return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                   console.log("\n\n*** Ending threads *** \n\n");
                   parentResolve("");

              });
            });  
    }
```

The worker code is as follows

```
web3 = require('web3');
Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
const { Worker, parentPort, workerData } = require("worker_threads");  
parentPort.postMessage("inside worker : " + workerData.id);
```

Comment: HI, please post the crash error you are getting.

Comment: Unfortumately, there was no error in any logs. I even tried prrocess.uncaughtexception but there was no error. it just crashes.
I was able to narrow down by trial and error and eventually found out that require('web3') is the cause.

Comment: Can you post your code? Especially how you require and create new workers.

Comment: Try commenting and uncommenting the first line of mainthread.
If we comment the require web3 in main thread,  the test method will run thrice
otherwise , test method will exit after first call.

Comment: Works fine for me, no crash with or without the first line in either file commented out. Might be some weird out of memory error? Still weird you don't have any error in your terminal or any log file.

Comment: Just an update,
the var code worked for the standalone code 
I am facing the crash after I introduced app i..e calling from front end.  I'm updating the code

Comment: second call to "localhost:8080/test" is crashing

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs   Can you please tell me which web3 version you are using?
I do see a memory leak issue in the logs

Comment: I did `yarn add web3` a few minutes prior to that comment, so whatever the `latest` version is. _Actually I still got the `package.json` and it says `^1.4.0`._ So maybe it is indeed an out of memory issue as I said. Good luck finding the cause!

Comment: Thanks for the details. If it's not too much trouble , could you please run the code above in your setup via appengine and let me know if it's failing.
i.e. hit the localhost:8080/test more than twice